# Are "auto income generators" scams or alternative investment channels?

Tags: scams

Not sure if anyone here might be familiar with the term "auto income generator," but it's a marketing gimmick where a person/website asks for an investment, sometimes as little as $1, and claims you'll be getting fast returns -- sometimes 200% within the next week I've heard.

As an example, one would claim to take $1 as an investment, and promise 6% returns daily, and 0.25% returns per hour -- better than stocks.

The claim is that all of the money they receive builds interest, and they then pour out more back.

There are very many sites like these online, and I've heard some people swear that they "work."

The idea is that you make a single deposit, and you're "set" -- money keeps coming in at a high return rate and your investment doubles, triples, and more -- supposedly seeming better than anything else.

My question is, does this really happen? I wouldn't give them a penny, but just wondering.

Comment: What do you think? If you wouldn't give them a penny then you have answered your own question - so what are you wondering about?

Comment: If it seems too good to be true, that's generally because it isn't true.

Comment: I'm not sure why the question is attracting so many down votes. It's an obvious yet opaque scam that I don't think has appeared yet on this site.

Comment: @DanielCarson We had a similar question a couple of months ago (see my dup flag above).  I'm not sure why the downvotes are there; I've voted both questions up.  I think the other question is quite a bit more detailed and already has a few great answers, but the score on that question is sitting at -3 right now....

Comment: If there's no clear explanation of what they're investing in and what the risks are, it's *definitely* a scam. If there is, it's probably a scam.

Answer (score -1):

> Are “auto income generators” scams or alternative investment channels?

I wouldn't go so far as to say that these are scams so much as grossly exaggerated marketing claims. If it sounds too good to be true then it usually is. Auto auto income generator, for example, hosts a site that you can use to produce revenue from ads. In order to get enough traffic to generate the amount of income they promise you have to put in a *lot* of work, hardly making it "automatic."

I can't find anything on auto bit coin builder, however. They promise to pay out an outrageously high fixed-return with vague descriptions about "investments." This is purely speculation since there is not very much information about this small site, but it may be a "pyramid" or "Ponzi" scheme. They promise a return higher than traditional investments, offer extra incentives for referrals, and offer a list of excuses for why funds may be pending even though the transfer happens "INSTANTLY" on their end. The fact that they only deal in crpytocurrency may also be an attempt to remain anonymous.